# Solving Systems by Gauss-Jordan Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm going through my textbook solving the practice problems, I haven't had any trouble solving systems that are already in row-echelon form, or reduced row-echelon form. However, I'm struggling with using the Gaussian and Gauss-Jordan methods to get them to this point. One of the questions I have is:

$$x_1+x_2+2x_3=8$$
$$-x_1-2x_2+3x_3=1$$
$$3x_1-7x_2+4x_3=10$$

Which as an augmented matrix would be:

$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 8\\
-1 & -2 & 3 & 1\\
3 & -7 & 4 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

I understand the first step, which is to take a multiple of 1, that when added would set -1 to 0, which in this case would be 1. And this would give me:

$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 8\\
0 & -1 & 4 & 2\\
3 & -7 & 4 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

But after this I'm lost as to what I should do next, or if I even did the first step properly. Can any show me how to solve using this method?

Comment: If equation 1 is correct the augmented matrix is $$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 8\\
-1 & -2 & 3 & 1\\
3 & -7 & 4 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why would you subtract 1 from $x_2$ and $x_3$ in the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the following thirteen steps,  Rx (like R1, R2 or R3) refers to the matrix row number:

- Swap R1 with R3
- Add R1/3 to R2
- Multiply R2 by -3/13
- Subtract R1/3 from R3
- Multiply (3/2)R3
- Swap R2 with R3
- Subtract R2/5 from R3
- Multiply (-5/6)R3
- Subtract R3 from R2
- Subtract (4) R3 from R1
- Add (7/5) R2 to R1
- Divide R1 by 3
- Divide R2 by 5

You should arrive at a RREF of:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}1 & 0 & 0 & 3\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 2\end{array}\right]
$$
Now, you read the solution from the bottom up, so we have:

- $x_3 = 2$
- $x_2 = 1$
- $x_1 = 3$

You should of course check my work and verify that those value satisfy all three simultaneous equations!

Comment: Helpful solution/algorithm/direction! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I think the OP got it and sometimes they need a little nudge off the cliff sort of speak! :-)